# Let $(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,b), b>0$. Find $E\left[\sum \frac{X_i }{X_{(n)}}\right]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Let $(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,b), b>0$. Find $E\left[\sum \frac{X_i }{X_{(n)}}\right]$ where $X_{(n)} = \max_i X_i$.

It was suggested to use Basu's Theorem which I am unfamiliar with.

There are finitely many terms so we can rearrange using order statistics and write it as:

\begin{align}
E\left[\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{X_i }{X_{(n)}}\right] & = E\left[\frac{X_{(1)}}{X_{(n)}}\right] + E\left[\frac{X_{(2)}}{X_{(n)}}\right]+ \cdots +E[1] \\[8pt]
& = (n-1) E\left[\frac{X_i}{X_{(n)}}\right] + 1
\end{align}

If this is correct then I will need to calculate a conditional expectation to calculate this so I wanted to see if this is even correct before moving forward. Or if someone familiar with Basu's theorem can explain how I apply that here.

Comment: Use the fact that $X_i/X_{(n)}$ and $X_{(n)}$ are independent by Basu's theorem.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Why are those independent? If I understand some $X_{(n)}$ is complete for $b$, then I need $X_i/X_{(n)}$ would need to be ancillary correct? Do I then calculate the conditional expectation of the product? i.e.$E[XY] =E[YE[X|Y]]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed,

$$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}{X_{(n)}}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n E\left[\frac{X_{i}}{X_{(n)}}\right]=nE\left[\frac{X_1}{X_{(n)}}\right]$$

This can be evaluated by showing that $X_1/X_{(n)}$ is independent of $X_{(n)}$, so that

$$E\left[X_1\right]=E\left[\frac{X_1}{X_{(n)}}\cdot X_{(n)}\right]=E\left[\frac{X_1}{X_{(n)}}\right]\cdot E\left[X_{(n)}\right]$$

Thus giving $$E\left[\frac{X_1}{X_{(n)}}\right]=\frac{E\left[X_1\right]}{E\left[X_{(n)}\right]}$$

The independence can be argued using Basu's theorem since the distribution of $\frac{X_1}{X_{(n)}}=\frac{X_1/b}{X_{(n)}/b}$ is free of $b$ (making $\frac{X_1}{X_{(n)}}$ an ancillary statistic) and $X_{(n)}$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Basu's theorem says that a complete sufficient statistic is independent of an ancillary statistic.

To say that $X_{(n)} = \max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is sufficient for this family of distributions (parametrized by $b$) means that the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $X_{(n)}$ does not depend on the value of $b.$

To say that $X_{(n)}$ is complete means there is no function $g$ (not depending on $b$) for which $\operatorname E(g(X_{(n)}))$ remains equal to $0$ as $b$ changes.

To say that $\dfrac{X_i}{X_{(n)}}$ is an ancillary statistic means that its probability distribution remains the same as $b$ changes, even though $\dfrac{X_i}{X_{(n)}}$ depends on $(X_1,\ldots,X_n,b)$ only through $(X_1,\ldots,X_n).$

If all of that is shown, then what Basu's theorem tells you is that $\dfrac{X_i}{X_{(n)}}$  and $X_{(n)}$ are independent.

That is what makes it possible to conclude that the expected value of their product is the product of their expected values, and then the rest is routine.

Comment: I thought I explained this clearly in my answer. OP presumably knows the theorem and relevant definitions when he is talking about it.

Comment: @StubbornAtom : He said he didn't know Basu's theorem.